# Parse html head with more meta generator tag

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

I need to parse html pages and get the value of different generator tags.
For example I have this code:

```
   <meta name="generator" content="WordPress 5.2.2" />


   <meta name="generator" content="Powered by  Page Builder - drag and drop page builder for WordPress."/>

   <meta name="generator" content="PLUGINNAME ver:4.2.4 stt:66,65,1;" />
```

I'm using cheerio, my problem is to find a query that extract content for every

Here is my code now:

```
    request('https://example.com', function (error, response, htmlBody) {
   const $ = cheerio.load(htmlBody);
  console.log($("meta[name='generator']"); // show a very long object that can't be parse in JSON

  console.log($("meta").get(1).attr("content")); // only show the first
```

}

Actually I get an object that is a nested circular json, and since I can't parse this object I'm not able to extract any information.

Comment: Your code as error and `$("meta[name='generator']")` return a jquery object which should have `each` method to iterate over the NodeList stored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jQuery [each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/) function to iterate all the meta elements

```
 $("meta[name='generator']").each(function(index) {
     console.log(this.content);
 })
```

Output:

```
WordPress 5.2.2 

Powered by  Page Builder - drag and drop page builder for WordPress. 

PLUGINNAME ver:4.2.4 stt:66,65,1;
```

Working JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/u0dbkp4j/